# Why am I getting different date formats from using AdapterDateFnsJalali and AdapterDayjs in my material-ui DatePicker with LocalizationProvider?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend, material-design

I have new issue with data picker in matrail ui X ,  AdapterDateFnsJalali in LocalizationProvider

when i use dateAdapter={AdapterDateFnsJalali} in LocalizationProvider , in slotProps={{day : (ownerState)}},
data of ownerState , part day object , i got a full data time string !
but when i use AdapterDayjs in dateAdapter , in slotProps={{day : (ownerState)}} , ownerState part of day , i got information about every day month and years ! why ?

in this case i got full string time stamp :

```
<LocalizationProvider
    dateAdapter={AdapterDateFnsJalali} // i use AdapterDateFnsJalali
    adapterLocale={faJalali}
    localeText={faIR.components.MuiLocalizationProvider.defaultProps.localeText}  >
    <DemoContainer components={['DatePicker']}>
        <DatePicker
            label="date"
            clearable
            slotProps={{
                day: (ownerState) => {
                    const DATES = {
                        month : ownerState.day['$M'], //i got string full time stamp !!
                        day : ownerState.day['$D'], //i got string full time stamp !!
                    }
                }
            }}
        />
    </DemoContainer>
</LocalizationProvider>

but in this case i got full info about date

<LocalizationProvider
    dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} //i use AdapterDayjs
>
    <DemoContainer components={['DatePicker']}>
        <DatePicker
            label="date"
            clearable
            slotProps={{
                day: (ownerState) => {
                    const DATES = {
                        month : ownerState.day['$M'], i got courrect info about each month 
                        day : ownerState.day['$D'],i got courrect info about each day
                    }
                }
            }}
        />
    </DemoContainer>
</LocalizationProvider>
```

```
should i got information about date like AdapterDayjs !

<LocalizationProvider
    dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}  //i use AdapterDayjs
>
    <DemoContainer components={['DatePicker']}>
        <DatePicker
            label="date"
            clearable
            slotProps={{
                day: (ownerState) => {
                    const DATES = {
                        month : ownerState.day['$M'],  i got courrect info about each month 
                        day : ownerState.day['$D'] ,i got courrect info about each day
                    }
                }
            }}
        />
    </DemoContainer>
</LocalizationProvider>
```

I want to compare the number of each day from my api with the number of each day in the material calendar and change it to a specific day if necessary, but this current information from the calendar, the day section "day: ownerState.day.getDay()", for example, It gives the third day of the week, while I want the numbers of each days like 1 2 3 4 ... 31!also i want my data be jalali format !